# Elasticsearch multi-search by tags

Tags: arrays, elasticsearch

My elasticsearch index store documents like these :

```
{
  "id": "123",
  "name": "My super object",
  "tags": [
    "level1",
    "level2-A",
    "level3-A-a"
  ]
}
```

or

```
{
  "id": "234",
  "name": "My super object",
  "tags": [
    "level1",
    "level2-B",
    "level3-B-a"
  ]
}
```

Tags representing a tree of navigation.

```
level1 -> level2-A -> level3-A-a
       -> level2-B -> level3-B-a
                   -> level3-B-b
```

I would like in one query be able to retreive, for a set of tags, up to ten objects tagged for each tags.

An example is easier to understand :

For level2-A and level2-B I would like to retreive up to 10 objects tagged with level2-A and level2-B.

Is there a way to do that in one query, instead of querying for each tag ?

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding the problem correctly, you could use the [`limit` filter](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-limit-filter.html) within a separate bool query for each tag that you care about.

For example... let's say I index 10 documents like this:

`{"tags": ["a"]}`

and 10 like this:

`{"tags": ["b"]}`

If I want a query that will give me 3 documents with an `"a"` tag and 3 documents with a `"b"` tag, this would work:

`{
      "query": {"match_all": {}},
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
          "should": [
            {
              "bool": {
                "must": [
                  {
                    "term": {"tags": "a"}
                  },
                  {
                    "limit": {"value": 3}
                  }
                ]
              }
            },
            {
              "bool": {
                "must": [
                  {
                    "term": {"tags": "b"}
                  },
                  {
                    "limit": {"value": 3}
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }`

However, if you have documents that have *multiple* tags, you might get cases where you have more than your limit for any one tag. Here's what I mean by that...

Let's say I index 3 documents with tags `["a"]`, and then 3 documents with tags `["a", "b"]`. If you perform the same query as above, you could possibly get 6 documents with `"a"` - three of them that have only `"a"`, and three that have `"a"` and `"b"`. If that kind of behavior is acceptable for your use case though, then that query above should work.

Caveat: the `limit` filter limits the number of documents that are considered *at the shard level*, not at the index level. If you have multiple shards in your index (which I suspect you probably do), then this approach won't work. I think in that case you'd really just have to do multiple queries.